# Collect flat array of deep nested data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have dictionary:

```
var objectSchemasList = {
  1: [
    {
        name: 'list_field1_1',
      uuid: 'uuid1',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'list_field1_2',
      uuid: 'uuid2',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: null
    },
  ],
  2: [
    {
        name: 'list_field2_1',
      uuid: 'uuid3',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: null
    },
    {
        name: 'list_field2_2',
      uuid: 'uuid4',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: null
    },
  ],
  3: [
    {
        name: 'list_field3_1',
      uuid: 'uuid5',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'list_field3_2',
      uuid: 'uuid6',
      fieldObjectSchemaId: null
    },
  ],
}
```

And array of related data to it:

```
const objectSchemaFields = [
    {
    name: 'field_1',
    uuid: '_uuid1',
    fieldObjectSchemaId: null
  },
  {
    name: 'field_2',
    uuid: '_uuid2',
    fieldObjectSchemaId: null
  },
  {
    name: 'field_3',
    uuid: '_uuid3',
    fieldObjectSchemaId: 1
  },
];
```

It means that every object schema field can contain inside themselves other fields. That are linked by `fieldObjectSchemaId`. This mean that `objectSchemaFields[2]` element use `objectSchemasList[objectSchemaFields[2].fieldObjectSchemaId]`. That also uses `objectSchemasList[2]` and so on. It can be nested infinitely. I want to get flat array from this structure. Here i [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/qm3Ldehp/1/). Final array should be flat and has only `path, name, uuid` properties. Where path consists of concatenation of parent name and all nested child names splitted by point. For example result should be:

```
const result = [
  {
    path: 'field_1',
    name: 'field_1',
    uuid: '_uuid1',
    },
  {
    path: 'field_2',
        name: 'field_2',
    uuid: '_uuid2',
    },
  {
    path: 'field_3',
    name: 'field_3',
    uuid: '_uuid3',
  },
  {
    path: 'field_3.list_field1_1',
    name: 'list_field1_1',
    uuid: 'uuid1',
  },
  {
    path: 'field_3.list_field1_1.list_field2_1',
    name: 'list_field2_1',
    uuid: 'uuid3',
  },
  {
    path: 'field_3.list_field1_1.list_field2_2',
    name: 'list_field2_2',
    uuid: 'uuid4',
  },
  {
    path: 'field_3.list_field1_2',
    name: 'list_field1_2',
    uuid: 'uuid2',
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good use case for map, because you still need to return the original object together with child objects, and you need to flatten it afterwards. Better stick with plain old array variable, or use `reduce` if you want to be fancy.

```
var output = [];

function processObject(path, obj) {
  path = path.concat([obj.name]);
  output.push({
    path: path.join("."),
    name: obj.name,
    uuid: obj.uuid,
  });
  var schema = objectSchemasList[obj.fieldObjectSchemaId];
  if (schema) {
    schema.forEach(processObject.bind(null, path));
  }
}

objectSchemaFields.forEach(processObject.bind(null, []));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m8t54bv5/

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the arrays with a recursive call of a flattening function.

```js
function flat(p) {
    return function (r, { name, uuid, fieldObjectSchemaId }) {
        var path = p + (p && '.') + name;
        r.push({ path, name, uuid });
        return (objectSchemasList[fieldObjectSchemaId] || []).reduce(flat(path), r);
    };
}

var objectSchemasList = { 1: [{ name: 'list_field1_1', uuid: 'uuid1', fieldObjectSchemaId: 2 }, { name: 'list_field1_2', uuid: 'uuid2', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }], 2: [{ name: 'list_field2_1', uuid: 'uuid3', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }, { name: 'list_field2_2', uuid: 'uuid4', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }], 3: [{ name: 'list_field3_1', uuid: 'uuid5', fieldObjectSchemaId: 1 }, { name: 'list_field3_2', uuid: 'uuid6', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }] },
    objectSchemaFields = [{ name: 'field_1', uuid: '_uuid1', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }, { name: 'field_2', uuid: '_uuid2', fieldObjectSchemaId: null }, { name: 'field_3', uuid: '_uuid3', fieldObjectSchemaId: 1 }],
    result = objectSchemaFields.reduce(flat(''), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use concat in a reducer, you're essentially cloning the array for every item, resulting in O(n^2) complexity. If you try to use it on an array with a few thousand items, it will be unacceptably slow: https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-global-array/1